# Any way to treat ASP.NET Identity like a membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

To be clear, I am aware that the Identity model does not implement anything to do with the membership provider model.

Since MS seems to have abandoned the MembershipProvider model in their latest web code and Visual studio as too limited, and I have to admit that it was often frustrating to work with, it seems they would replace it with something that, at least, out of the box did what a standard membership provider could do out of the box.

While there's certainly a market for claims-based authentication and authorization, simple authentication and role-based authorization still work quite well for a great deal of web applications... especially business applications that, for security/ audit reasons, users should NOT be allowed to register for, but rather be provisioned upon verification that all the proper steps have been followed.

With the Membership Provider, you could add users, assign roles, etc., right from within Visual Studio.  I don't see this sort of thing available any more, and it baffles me that MS would think that such a style of provisioning would no longer have value.

I'm building my first MVC5 application, and I find myself seriously considering ripping this stuff out and going with something that I know works, but I really don't want to put obsoleted tech into a brand new project.

Is there any documented way to explicitly provision users and assign roles like what was available in the MembershipProvider, preferably within Visual Studio?  I'm not suggesting it has to be exactly the same, or use the same interface, but at least have the same *capability*... i.e., create new users in a database, and assign roles to them.

Comment: is this a rant or a question :)  Just kidding, I know what you are asking.  In my opinion, it isn't that hard to just create a database with users and roles and then overwrite the `OnAuthorize` method in MVC to create your own `[Authenticate]` attribute.  I have done this several times and it's pretty easy and extensible.  For the login, you must also leverage `FormsAuthentication` to create the auth cookie.  But, it's pretty simple.

Comment: Yeah I was worried this would come across as a rant, but I really would like to just use this in a very simple manner.

Comment: @user1477388 are you saying you can do that with the ASP.NET Identity model?  Can you point me to a blog or instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Will this help you [Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)?  This uses Azure but you probably don't have to.

Comment: @user1477388 Ugh... roll my own?  That's a lot more work than I was planning on doing.

Comment: Once you do it once it comes naturally :)  Plus you'll have the confidence of knowing how everything works.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it right but what about getting rid of Identity and simply use membership provider? I see no reason that the technique will not work.

Comment: @sprinter252 Yeah I could do that, but I'd prefer not to put obsoleted tech into a brand new project.  It just rubs me the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) from [Brok Allen](http://brockallen.com/). I have not used it myself, but it sounds promising. He also started [IdentityReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot) that is also looks like an alternative to MS library.